# Word COM/OLE/VBA: How to save to/load from memory a document?

Tags: vba, ms-word, ole

According to the 'Microsoft Office Word™ 2003 Visual Basic Reference', it seems the Document object can only load a file from disk or save a file to disk. Is it possible to save a document to memory or load a document from memory? Since I need to save the documents to a database instead of to disk files. I use Delphi.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can I put the thread to the top by adding a comment ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Office does support opening a file from internet with the WEBDAV protocol. I guess it supports the IPersistMoniker interface. Check DSOFramer's source code for more information.
Note DSOFramer isn't supported and Office may not support the interfaces used in DSOFramer in the future.

Comment: Thank you Sheng Jiang, I think I better off resort to the ordinary 'save to disk' methods and the likes.